# How can I create "onclick" event in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chromium

**Here is my `main.html` file:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 16 - https://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="Chromium_Güncelleştirici_Eklenti_Projesi.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_Image1" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:320px;height:50px;z-index:0;">
<img src="Assets/baslik.png" id="Image1" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Image7" style="left:0px;top:160px;width:320px;height:35px;z-index:1;">
<img src="Assets/guncellestirmeleriDenetlePasif.png" id="Image2" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Image3" style="left:0px;top:87px;width:320px;height:36px;z-index:3;">
<img src="Assets/ayarlarPasif.png" id="Image3" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Image4" style="left:0px;top:123px;width:320px;height:72px;z-index:4;">
<img src="Assets/hakkindaPasif.png" id="Image4" alt=""></div>
<script src="../Data/deneme.js" type="module">
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my `deneme.js` file:**

```
document.addEventListener
(
    'DOMContentLoaded',
    function()
    {
        var dugme = document.getElementById('Image2');
        
        dugme.addEventListener
        (
            'click',
            function()
            {
                console.log('Merhaba Dünya!');
            }
        );
    }
);
```

But the problem is, when I click the `Image2`, the browser does not respond.

I did not write JS code into my `main.html` file; because Chromium blocks my extension (Content Security Policy).

So, what should I do?

Comment: This fragment of code is fine so you need to investigate further. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the script tag.

Try below html, it should work fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 16 - https://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="Chromium_Güncelleştirici_Eklenti_Projesi.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_Image1" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:320px;height:50px;z-index:0;">
<img src="Assets/baslik.png" id="Image1" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Image7" style="left:0px;top:160px;width:320px;height:35px;z-index:1;">
<img src="Assets/guncellestirmeleriDenetlePasif.png" id="Image2" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Image3" style="left:0px;top:87px;width:320px;height:36px;z-index:3;">
<img src="Assets/ayarlarPasif.png" id="Image3" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Image4" style="left:0px;top:123px;width:320px;height:72px;z-index:4;">
<img src="Assets/hakkindaPasif.png" id="Image4" alt=""></div>
<script src="../Data/deneme.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm. By the way, I have realized that JS is too dangerous language. For example, someone can use "Native Messaging" API in order to hack the computer.